# All possible k combinations of n elements c++

Tags: c++, combinatorics

I have an input of k and n (0≤k≤n). And for the input (2 3) I expect this code to produce the output: 
0 1

0 2

1 2

However I'm getting just 0 1. How can this be fixed?

Thank you.

```
void comb(int N, int K)
{
    std::string bitmask(K, 1);
    bitmask.resize(N, 0);

    do {
        for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        {
            if (bitmask[i]) std::cout << " " << i;
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    } while (std::prev_permutation(bitmask.begin(), bitmask.end()));
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    int k;
    cin >> n >> k;
    comb(n, k);
}
```

Comment: Seems to works [here](https://ideone.com/Fkxr2s) (with correct input `3 2` and not `2 3` to have `k < n`).

Comment: If you have `k = 3; n = 2`, then you have in fact result for `k = n = 2`.

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks! Now I see that after changing n & k in comb(n, k); the output works as expected.